# SQL Syntax error on commented T-SQL only in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I had an error occur while installing on a customer site using SQL Server 2012.  I was able to reproduce the syntax error locally on SQLExpress 2012.  The same DDL script runs fine under 2008 R2 but fails with "Incorrect syntax near '44445'".

Checking the SQL that is being executed, the text '44445' is commented out. Again, this SQL works on 2008 R2. The last line posted is the syntax offender.  Notice, it is commented out as is most of this example.

```
[snipped]    
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM ::fn_listextendedproperty(N'Updatable' , N'USER',N'dbo', N'TABLE',N'PublishLog', NULL,NULL))
EXEC dbo.sp_addextendedproperty @name=N'Updatable', @value=N'True' , @level0type=N'USER',@level0name=N'dbo', @level1type=N'TABLE',@level1name=N'PublishLog'
GO

--SET ANSI_NULLS ON
--GO
--SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
--GO
--IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM dbo.sysobjects WHERE id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[MetaData]') AND OBJECTPROPERTY(id, N'IsUserTable') = 1)
--BEGIN
--CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MetaData](
--  [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
--  [DataName] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
--  [DataDescription] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
-- CONSTRAINT [MetaData_PK] PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED 
--(
--  [ID] ASC
--) ON [PRIMARY]
--) ON [PRIMARY]
--END
--GO

--SET ANSI_NULLS ON
--GO

--SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF
--GO

--IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM dbo.sysobjects WHERE id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[T_MetaData_DTrig]') AND OBJECTPROPERTY(id, N'IsTrigger') = 1)
--EXEC dbo.sp_executesql @statement = N'CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[T_MetaData_DTrig] ON [dbo].[MetaData] FOR DELETE AS
--SET NOCOUNT ON
--/* * PREVENT DELETES IF DEPENDENT RECORDS IN ''DocumentsData'' */
--IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM deleted, DocumentsData WHERE (deleted.ID = DocumentsData.MetaTagsID)) > 0
--    BEGIN
--        RAISERROR 44445 ''The record can''''t be deleted or changed. Since related records exist in table ''''DocumentsData'''', referential integrity rules would be violated.''
--        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
--    END

[snipped]
```

Comment: Are you sure no word wrap has happened when trying to run on SQL Server 2012?

Comment: Have you tried commenting the line using `/* ... */` instead?

Comment: I checked for word wrapping/hidden and unprintable characters.  Removing the commented code, the DDL works fine.  I can simply remove the code and deliver it but I was curious if anyone else had seen this behavior.'

Answer (score 2):

They discontinued that `RAISERROR` syntax.  Now, you "NEED" the parentesis.

Read this: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144262.aspx

and search for "RAISERROR"

Comment: Except it should be ignored if it's commented out.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that raise error syntax has changed 
2008 R2 has raiseerror(id, msg) - [see here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177497%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)
For 2012 its raiseerror(msg, id) - [see here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178592.aspx)

So using `RAISERROR(''test'',44445, 1)` in your example above works

Edit - I've just checked and `RAISERROR(''test'',44445, 1)` also works in 2008 R2

Comment: I read both your citations and don't see the difference.  The msgid is optional.  In the second citation for 2012, example A and C omit a message number relying only on the state and severity.  The example B is similar to my code.

What I did notice is that all examples use state and severity that is missing in my code.